# How do i create a field in access database that shows the record index in "A1,A2..... H12" format?

Tags: microsoft-access

[image]

How do I create a field that automatically converts the index value in a record to cell number, as in the picture?

I have 96 cells starting with A1 and ending with H12, like this:

[image]

Comment: Convert what to what exactly? Please give some examples.

Comment: 1 --> A1
2 --> A2
96 --> H12

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA function that can then be called in a query or in a form or report or in VBA:

```vb
Public Function JoinFromSql(DataSource As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, s As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(DataSource, dbOpenForwardOnly)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If s = "" Then
            s = Nz(rs(0))
        Else
            s = s & Delimiter & Nz(rs(0))
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close: Set db = Nothing
    JoinFromRecordset = s
End Function
```

You would call it like this:

```vb
JoinFromSql("SELECT [Cell number] FROM Table1 ORDER BY [Index]")
```

The function above uses `DAO`. If you prefer `ADODB` you can write a similar function as:

```vb
Public Function JoinFromSql(DataSource As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, s As String

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open DataSourceName, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If s = "" Then
            s = Nz(rs(0))
        Else
            s = s & Delimiter & Nz(rs(0))
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    cnn.Close: Set cnn = Nothing
End Function
```